# Solution to second order ODE with non-negative loadings

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I have found many references to general solutions of ODEs of the form
$$
ay(x)''+by(x)'+cy(x)=0,
$$
and outlined "methods" for the case where $a,b,c$ are non-constant.  If I were to assume that $b=0$ and $a,c$ are positive functions of x then is there a known explicit general solution?

Comment: set $$y=e^{\lambda x}$$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner:  your suggestion $y = e^{\lambda x}$ work fine as long as $a$, $b$, and $c$ are constant, which is not the case here,

Comment: oh i have misreaded the text in my case it was $$a,b,c$$ are constant, sorry

Comment: Can the strict positivity be used?  To reduce to a similar case?